# coreos ip_conntrack_tcp_be_liberal parameter change

Tags: coreos

to be able to apply the solution described in https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/03/29/kube-proxy-subtleties-debugging-an-intermittent-connection-reset/ I need to find a way instead of "echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/netfilter/ip_conntrack_tcp_be_liberal" on CoreOS, but could not achieve that. How can I apply this solution for CoreOS?

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick:

```
storage:
  files:
    # remove with update to 1.15 https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/74840
    # hotfix for https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/03/29/kube-proxy-subtleties-debugging-an-intermittent-connection-reset/
    - path: /etc/modules-load.d/ip.conf
      filesystem: root
      mode: 0644
      contents:
        inline: |
          ip_conntrack
    - path: /etc/sysctl.d/ip.conf
      filesystem: root
      mode: 0644
      contents:
        inline: |
          net.netfilter.ip_conntrack_tcp_be_liberal=1
```

found at core os documentation https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/other-settings.html#tuning-sysctl-parameters